# Google Drive API: list collections

Tags: google-drive-api

How can we manage Google Drive using Google Drive API, which requires

1. list collections and its children
2. create file and collection
3. rename/move/copy files and collections

Answer (score 3):

I can't try this yet as I don't have access to google drive, but as far as I know google drive is a google docs rebrand, so probably the older google docs api's still work if you n eed to work with collections. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_collections_and_their_contents

Comment: When I try to list a collection with Google Docs API, it lists only files/collections created with Google Docs, not lists newly created files with Google Drive

Comment: I'm trying this as well in Ruby, seems not doable properly.. I just wish Google Drive would add files listing in their four APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Now we have Google Drive SDK v2, which supposedly can solve your problems.